# Docker nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "backend"

Tags: nginx, flask, docker-compose

I'm trying to set up a flask server using uWSGI combined with the [linuxserver/letsencrypt](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/letsencrypt/) container using `docker-compose`. I used the `docker-compose.yml` file below already with another nginx server. The problem is that the nginx container cannot find my `backend` flask container, and can therefore not perform the `uwsgi_pass` to it.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.1'
services:

    nginx:
      image: linuxserver/letsencrypt
      ports:
        - "80:80"
        - "443:443"
      volumes:
        - ./data/nginx/nginx.conf:/config/nginx/site-confs/default
        - ./data/nginx/uwsgi_params:/config/nginx/uwsgi_params
      depends_on:
        - backend
      networks:
        - backend
      container_name: nginx
      environment:
        - PUID=1000
        - PGID=1000
        - (+ other settings)


    backend:
        build: ./backend
        container_name: flask
        restart: always
        links:
            - db
        volumes:
            - ./backend:/app
            - ./managed:/managed
        expose: 
            - 8080

    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        container_name: db
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"


volumes:
  flask-db:

networks:
  backend:
```

I attempted connecting them using `links`, `depends_on` and `networks`, but nothing seems to work.

`nginx.conf`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.example.com;
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.example.com;
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass backend:8080;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


        if ($request_method = 'POST') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
        }
        if ($request_method = 'GET') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
        }
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example.com;
    server_tokens off;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass backend:8080;
        proxy_set_header    Host                $http_host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

The error in the `nginx` container is:

```
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "backend" in /config/nginx/site-confs/default:18
```

I should also mention that the `./data/nginx/uwsgi_params` volume is simply the list of `uwsgi` commands

How can I succeed to make the `backend` container accessible from the `nginx` container?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `depends_on` attribute in the `docker-compose` file like:

```
nginx:
  depends_on:
    - backend
```